# Proof/reference for a variant of Pontryagin duality

Tags: gr.group-theory, duality, haar-measure

Let $X,X'$ be locally compact abelian groups with a non-degenerate quadratic form 
$\left<\bullet ,\bullet \right>\colon X\times X' \to \mu_{l}$,
where $l$ is a prime, and $\mu_l$ the group of $l$-roots of unity.
For a closed subgroup $X_0\subseteq X$, denote by $X_0^{\perp}= \{x'\in X': \left<X_0,x'\right>=1\}$.

I look for a simple proof, or a reference for following statement, that I couldn't find in the literature:

Theorem: $X_0=X_0^{\perp\perp}$ for every closed subgroup $X_0\leq X$.

Comment: What is a quadratic form in this setting?  Is it just a bi-multiplicative map?

Comment: @LSpice Yes. However, I think of $X$ as an additive group (or Z-module) so it is a bi-linear map.

Comment: Sorry, I just caught that $\ell$ is a prime.  Isn't this just a statement about vector spaces over $\mathbb F_\ell$?

Comment: What do you mean? $X$ and $X'$ are not vector spaces. Do you a reduction to this case ? Maybe it factors through $X/lX$?

Comment: Indeed, $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ does factor through $X/\ell X \otimes_{\mathbb F_\ell} X'/\ell X'$, since $\langle\ell X, X'\rangle = \langle X, \ell X'\rangle = \langle X, X'\rangle^\ell = 1$.